# Adapting diverging stacked bar chart to use general update pattern

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have been working with a stacked bar chart example available [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/b5935342c6d21928111928401e2c8608) with the following code:

```
var data = [
  {month: "Q1-2016", apples: 3840, bananas: 1920, cherries: -1960, dates: -400},
  {month: "Q2-2016", apples: 1600, bananas: 1440, cherries: -960, dates: -400},
  {month: "Q3-2016", apples:  640, bananas:  960, cherries: -640, dates: -600},
  {month: "Q4-2016", apples:  320, bananas:  480, cherries: -640, dates: -400}
];

var series = d3.stack()
    .keys(["apples", "bananas", "cherries", "dates"])
    .offset(d3.stackOffsetDiverging)
    (data);

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60},
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.month; }))
    .rangeRound([margin.left, width - margin.right])
    .padding(0.1);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([d3.min(series, stackMin), d3.max(series, stackMax)])
    .rangeRound([height - margin.bottom, margin.top]);

var z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

svg.append("g")
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(series)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d; })
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth)
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data.month); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })

svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + y(0) + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ",0)")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

function stackMin(serie) {
  return d3.min(serie, function(d) { return d[0]; });
}

function stackMax(serie) {
  return d3.max(serie, function(d) { return d[1]; });
}
```

The code as per the example won't support transitions or redraws so I have been trying to apply the principles of the [general update pattern](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218) to it so I can use it in my application.

I am not familiar with D3v4 and the nature of the 'appends' confuses me. I see two 'enters' in the same append method chain so I attempted to seperate them into their own declarations like:

```
var join1 = .selectAll("g")
      .data(series)

var join2Update = .selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d; })

var join2Enter= join2.enter()

join2Enter
 .append("rect")
 .merge(join2Update)
 .transition()
 .attr("width", x.bandwidth)
 .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data.month); })
 .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
 .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
```

But it doesn't do much except break the chart! I'm frankly a bit lost in the whole thing and any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did quiet a few changes in your code to make it updateable, I'll point out some of the changes I made, if there's anything else that's unclear you can just ask.

The main thing I've changed is that in our dataset we have two categories for the sake of simplicity so that we can update our data based on input like this

```
var keys = ["apples" + input, "bananas" + input];
```

And the input variable here being initially selected like this

```
var input = d3.selectAll(".opt").property("value");
```

and when we manually update it we get the new data like this

```
d3.selectAll(".opt").on("change", function() {
    update(data, this.value)
})
```

Instead of appending a g elemnt dirctly in conjunction with the rect, we create a bar group that holds the `series` dataset and later refernce it with yet another variable.

```
var barGroups = svg.selectAll("g.layer")
    .data(series);

barGroups.exit().remove();

barGroups.enter().insert("g", ".x-axis")
  .classed('layer', true);
```

Here's the Update pattern part of the code that you mentioned earlier:

```
var bars = svg.selectAll("g.layer").selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d; });

bars.exit().remove();

bars = bars
    .enter()
.append("rect")
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("x", d => x(d.data.month))
  .merge(bars)

bars.transition().duration(750)
    .attr("y", d => y(d[1]))
    .attr("height", d => Math.abs(y(d[0])) - y(d[1]));
```

And that should be it, have a look at the snippet below to see how it all works.

```js
var data = [
  {month: "Q1-2016", apples_1: -400, bananas_1: 920, apples_2: -196, bananas_2: 840},
  {month: "Q2-2016", apples_1: -400, bananas_1: 440, apples_2: -960, bananas_2: 600},
  {month: "Q3-2016", apples_1: -600, bananas_1: 960, apples_2: -640, bananas_2: 640},
  {month: "Q4-2016", apples_1: -400, bananas_1: 480, apples_2: -640, bananas_2: 320}
];

var margin = {top: 35, right: 145, bottom: 35, left: 45},
    width = 650 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 450 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("#chart")
 .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
 .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
 .attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, width])
    .padding(0.1);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range(["steelblue","darkorange"]);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class","x-axis");

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y-axis");

var input = d3.selectAll(".opt").property("value");

d3.selectAll(".opt").on("change", function() {
 update(data, this.value)
})

update(data, input);

function update(data, input) {

 var keys = ["apples" + input, "bananas" + input];
  
 var series = d3.stack()
  .keys(keys)
  .offset(d3.stackOffsetDiverging)
  (data);

 x.domain(data.map(d => d.month));

 y.domain([
  d3.min(series, stackMin), 
  d3.max(series, stackMax)
 ]).nice();

    var barGroups = svg.selectAll("g.layer")
     .data(series);

    barGroups.exit().remove();

    barGroups.enter().insert("g", ".x-axis")
      .classed('layer', true);
    
    svg.selectAll("g.layer")
     .transition().duration(750)
     .attr("fill", d => z(d.key));
    
    var bars = svg.selectAll("g.layer").selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d; });
  
 bars.exit().remove();
    
    bars = bars
     .enter()
    .append("rect")
     .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
     .attr("x", d => x(d.data.month))
      .merge(bars)

    bars.transition().duration(750)
     .attr("y", d => y(d[1]))
     .attr("height", d => Math.abs(y(d[0])) - y(d[1]));
 
 svg.selectAll(".x-axis").transition().duration(750)
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + y(0) + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

 svg.selectAll(".y-axis").transition().duration(750)
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
 
 function stackMin(serie) {
  return d3.min(serie, function(d) { return d[0]; });
 }
 
 function stackMax(serie) {
   return d3.max(serie, function(d) { return d[1]; });
 }

}
```

```css
body {
 margin: auto;
 width: 850px;
}
```

```html
<meta charset ="utf-8">

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
select something
<select class="opt">
 <option value="_1">1</option>
 <option value="_2">2</option>
</select><br>

<svg id="chart"></svg>
```

Comment: This is a superb answer. Thank you for taking the time to work on it. I can see the application of the update pattern much more clearly in the code. Unfortunately I am having trouble with the transitions but that is because of my implementation of the above in an Ember component which is out of scope of the original question.

Comment: @Abuelo No problem, sorry to hear that, I'm sure someone competent with ember could help you though.